# Should API gateway be coupled/uncoupled with the business logic

Tags: api, api-gateway

We are trying to build an API gateway in front of our application (we may split the application to micro services ASAP), and we meet some problems.

**1** - different API types.

There are two kinds APIs in our application, most of them will be used by ourselves(user login/logout, news add/remove), we call them `Self-used API` here. And some of APIs will be allowed to used by third party, we call them `Open API` here.

Should all of them get through the gateway?

**2** - different authentication

Self-used API may require the user login-ed or have related permissions, the Open API will require the third-party app take a key which we will use to identify and limit the request rate.

Should all kinds of authentication completed in the gateway?  If yes, the Self-used api authentication is business related, does it mean that this api gateway can not be shared by other application?

Furthermore, the third-party developer will create their application and get a key back, they can also update/remove the apps(Something like Google API Console).

I am not sure if this should be put in the gateway or another micro-service. IMO, I prefer to put these features in a new service, but the validation and rate limit is done in gateway, that means for each request, gateway will have to query the user, rate limit and other information by the key from the service, this  will make the gateway coupled with the business again.

Answer (score 0):

There are quite a few ways of implementing an API Gateway.  You can use different endpoints with a single API gateway.  Here are a few links that are relevant

Serverless blog "How to deploy multiple micro-services under one API domain with Serverless" https://serverless.com/blog/api-gateway-multiple-services/

Nginx "Do You Really Need Different Kinds of API Gateways? (Hint: No!)" https://www.nginx.com/blog/do-you-really-need-different-kinds-of-api-gateways-hint-no/

Sentialabs.io "Amazon API Gateway types, use cases and performance" https://www.sentialabs.io/2018/09/13/API-Gateway-Types-Compared.html

AWS API Gateway FAQs https://aws.amazon.com/api-gateway/faqs/

Think about the types of features you are trying to accomplish with your approach, and how API Gateway will help you address them.